# How to solve $u_{t}+u_{x}-u(x, t) =0$ with initial conditions $ u(x,0) = \phi (x) $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now, looking for some hints on how to go about this one. 
$$u_{t}+u_{x}-u(x, t) =0$$
With initial conditions 
$$ u(x,0) = \phi (x) $$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try the change of variable $v(t,x)=e^{-t}u(t,x)$ and then use the [Method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: Thanks, i see how this will work; although I'm a little confused on how the change of variable will effect the initial conditions for the equation

Comment: Actually, I think that the function can be separated by variables as: $u(t,x) = \psi (t)\phi (x) = {e^{ - t}}\phi (x)$

Comment: Never mind, it was very straight forward once I started working it out.

Answer (score 1):

Besides to [@AugSB](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193596/153337) 's hint, you can solve your equation by means of the separation of variables method. I will give you some hints and you may continue the solution to the end.

$${u_t} + {u_x} - u\left( {x,{\rm{ }}t} \right){\rm{ }} = 0$$

You can separate your function by variables as a function of $t$ and a function of $x$:

$$u(t,x) = \psi (t)\phi (x)$$

By substituting the functions above in your equations, you will find the solution:

$$
\begin{split}
\psi '\phi  + \psi \phi ' - \psi \phi  &= 0\\
\psi '\phi  - \psi \phi  &= \psi \phi '\\
(\psi ' - \psi )\phi  &= \psi \phi '\\
\frac{{\psi ' - \psi }}{\psi } &= \frac{{\phi '}}{\phi}
\end{split}
$$

Now, your PDE is turned into two separated ODEs which can be solved individually. If you go through solving the equations above, you will see that the function of variable $t$ is an exponential function as expressed in the other answer to your question.